# How to set time with date in momentjs

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time, momentjs

Does **momentjs** provide any option to set time with particular time ?

```js
var date = "2017-03-13";
var time = "18:00";

var timeAndDate = moment(date).startOf(time);

console.log(timeAndDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: `moment(date+' '+time)`?

Comment: It's probably a good time to [read the docs on parsing](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/)

Comment: @BenM not working

Comment: @chazsolo I will have a look

Comment: @MuhammedAthimannil It is working, please see my answer; and importantly, the working snippet.

Comment: @BenM some reason I am not able to upload screenshot at the moment. I will try later

Comment: @MuhammedAthimannil Have you seen my answer? It has two methods for achieving this. One using concatenation, and one using two `moment()` objects.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Moment.js does not provide a way to set the time of an existing moment through a string. Why not just concatenate the two:

```js
var date = "2017-03-13";
var time = "18:00";

var timeAndDate = moment(date + ' ' + time);

console.log(timeAndDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively, you can use two Moment objects and use the getters and setters. Although a far more verbose option, it could be useful if you can't use concatenation:

```js
let dateStr = '2017-03-13',
    timeStr = '18:00',
    date    = moment(dateStr),
    time    = moment(timeStr, 'HH:mm');

date.set({
    hour:   time.get('hour'),
    minute: time.get('minute'),
    second: time.get('second')
});

console.log(date);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Concatenating is not a viable option if working with different time zones.

Answer (score 88):

Since this pops up in google results, moment now has a [`set(unit, value)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/set/) function and you can achieve this by:

```
const hours = 15;
const minutes = 32;
var date = moment("1946-05-21").set("hour", hours).set("minute", minutes);
```

or as a combined function

```
var date = moment("1946-05-21").set({"hour": 15, "minute": 32});
```

*Note: the `set` function requires the value to be Integer type*

Answer (score 11):

for today's date with a different time:

```
moment(12, "HH")
```

Answer (score 6):

Just incase anyone is wondering how to set the time on a *Date Object*, here's how I did it:

```
const dateObj = new Date();

const dateStr = dateObj.toISOString().split('T').shift();
const timeStr = '03:45';

const timeAndDate = moment(dateStr + ' ' + timeStr).toDate();
```

Comment: Really you should not be altering datetimes using string operations. That's what a library like moment is *for*. Better to use `moment(dateObj).hours(3).minutes(45)`

Answer (score 5):

```
var timeAndDate = moment(date).add(moment.duration(time))
```

When you have separated string for date and time you can parse first as date and second as duration and just add them. This should create `moment` with proper date and time

Comment: Please edit your answer and add some context by explaining how your answer solves the problem, instead of posting code-only answer. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24973335)

Comment: Does not give the accurate results.